# understanding the language of an argument in Bruns and Herzog Cor. 2.3.10

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

The following question is heavily related to the context of theorems 2.3.9 and 2.3.10 in the text *Cohen-Macaulay rings* by Bruns and Herzog.  My intention is to make this question as self-contained as possible, and I can expand on further details upon request.

Let $S$ be a commutative ring $a:=a_1,\dots,a_n$, $y:=y_1,\dots,y_n$ $S$-sequences such that $I:=(a) \subset \mathfrak{n}:=(y)$. Write $a_i = \sum a_{ji} y_j$ and let $\Delta$ be the determinant of the matrix $(a_{ji})$. Let $f_1,\dots,f_n$ be a basis of $S^n$ such that $d_y(f_i)=y_i$, where $d_y$ is the differential of the Koszul complex $K_{\bullet}(y)$, and define $u_i := \sum a_{ji} f_j$. Consider the augmented Koszul complex $K_{\bullet}(y,S/I)$ and the corresponding homology complex $H_{\bullet}(y,S/I)$. Then by Theorem 2.3.9 we have that $H_n(y,S/I)$ is generated by $\bar{u}_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \bar{u}_n = \Delta \bar{f}_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \bar{f}_n$, where $\bar{\xi}$ denotes class mod $I$ of $\xi$.

The proof of Corollary 2.3.10a aims in showing that $(I:n)/I \cong Hom_S(S/n,S/I)$ can be identified with $H_n(y,S/I)$. The authors write: "$\bar{u}_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \bar{u}_n$ maps to the residue class of $\Delta$ in $S/I$ by the homomorphism which sends $f_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge f_n$ to $1$ (and thus gives the identification $(I:n)/I \cong H_n(y,S/I)$)."

> Question: Even though I feel that there is not anything really hard involved, I cannot understand the quoted phrase. From where to where is this homomorphism that takes $f_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge f_n$ to $1$, and why its existence is enough for the identification?